# Showpare 6 custom snippets not shown on storefront

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I recently updated shopware to 6.4.18 and noticed that all custom snippets be issued empty on the storefront.

So instead of the value only the snippet name is given.

Does somebody know the cause and how to fix it?

EDIT:
I ask the support team of the plugin manufacturer of the theme I'm using.
They already know the bug and wrote a documentation for this bug:
https://themedocs-sw6.zenit.design/faq/fehler/textbausteine-zeigen-technischen-namen

Answer (score 4):

Let us have the solution posted here:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration#config-inheritance

ChildThemes should have set `configInheritance` in the `theme.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to run the command `bin/console theme:refresh` after your theme.json file change in order to make the changes visible. (Resource: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration#structure-of-theme-configuration)